# Refer to NULL in List of Values (Oracle APEX)

Tags: sql, oracle, null, oracle-apex, lov

So I have a List of Values, and I want to have a display value of "Yes" when the return value is NULL. I tried leaving the return value blank, and even writing null, but when I go to my table and use the LOV, instead of getting my return value "Yes", I still get

```
 -
```

Is there a proper way to refer to NULL in a list of values return value? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Apex are you on?

Comment: Application Express 4.2.5.00.08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you seeing the dash? In a report showing the information? If so, reports default nulls to dashes - see 'report attributes' -> 'show null values as'.

Otherwise, you may need to post what you're using for your LOV. And/or maybe an image of what you're seeing.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but this worked as a workaround for my situation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know that 3.x and earlier behave differently. I'm on 4.1, but I think 4.2 is the same.

In the "List of values" section of your page item definition, ensure that:

- Display Null Value is set to: Yes
- Null Display Value is set to: Yes
- Null Return Value is left blank

Comment: where is display null value? And the other two were already set with those options